# Deliver Python executable with any other installer

Tags: python-3.x

I need to deliver python executable(python-3.6.6) along with pip with the installer to run the python codes written. I can deliver the default python installer folder(which is created after the installation of python from python website) but this folder is very large.

I just need to deliver python executable and some packages in that folder with minimal size. Is there any best way to do this?

Comment: pyenv? cx_freeze? xars? what have you tried?

Comment: I don't need to convert my python scripts to exe here. I need to provide a python installer folder along with my installer. So that after installing my installer the end user can run python scripts.